# Unexpected pinned projects in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am running Visual Studio 2017 on my laptop. I usually work on several different projects/solutions everyday, and there are one project and one solution "pinned" on the MRU list of start screen and file list (the Explorer one).

The problem is, they are both quite old (~2 months since last opened), and I have never pinned them. They just stuck there. So now when I open Visual Studio, the third item is actually the real most recently used one.

I tried to remove the two entries from start screen and file list, they would just automatically pop up the next time I launch Visual Studio. I also tried to stop synchronizing settings via cloud, but it does not help (so it seems like a local issue). I cannot stand it anymore. I did not encounter this problem in previous versions.

What is the possible cause? Is this a bug that I should report to Microsoft (well, it may be recognized as an unimportant one though)? And how can it be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered the same issue under VS2017 and after few attempts I figured out a solution that may fix your problem.
First of all, after having closed all VS instances, delete the hex keys in your system registry that contains the path of your undesired projects.
In order to do that I've exported all the keys in a backup file, then searched for the occurences with a text editor. 
Just for reference, in my case the path was: 
Computer\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-2840329424-3192507804-1387616012-2346\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search\RecentApps{0D6B9660-F302-4C2A-82E4-FF89D03814E0}\RecentItems{AC7C50DF-34F3-4DA3-A6ED-45A6CF489220}

Then you have to remove from "ApplicationPrivateSettings.xml" file, the occurences of your projects that you want to remove.
The file is located here:
C:\Users{Username}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_0dae6c36

At last, update your visual studio to the latest version with all those tricks done. You shouldn't see all your annoying projects anymore.